# Using different node versions on centos 6

Tags: centos, node.js

I'm attempting to run different node js versions on my centos 6.
When I run `node -v`

I get `v10.16.0`

I then run `n`
And I can select

```
    node/8.16.0
  ο node/10.16.0
    node/11.0.0
```

I select `node/8/16.0` hit enter then nothing happens when I run node -v it still says v10.16.0

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, does it work if you [open a new terminal](https://github.com/tj/n/issues/261#issuecomment-97992811)?

Comment: Yup great, thank you!  @Freddy

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Freddy's comment.<sup>*</sup>

I restarted another terminal window and it worked.

<sub>*If this helps you please upvote his comment.</sub>